# Asp.Net MVC : Unable to apply Knockout binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a mvc project and I've used Knouckout.

with AppLogin I want to redirect to other action.
After the Redirecttoaction,I am in other view but the second applyBindings does not work

```
var Login;
$ (document) .ready (function () {
 Login = new LoginVM ();
 ko.applyBindings (Login, document.getElementById ("pnlLogin"));


});


function LoginVM () {
 var self = this;
 self.Name = ko.observable ();
 self.Password = ko.observable ();

self.AppLogin = function () {

                 window.location.href = "Main / MainPage";
                 ko.cleanNode (document.getElementById ( "pnlLogin"));
                 ko.applyBindings (Main, document.getElementById ("pnlMain"));

}


  }
```

Comment: I would think that once you set window.location.href to another location the javascript after it will no longer execute. You would have to do your second applyBindings actually on the MainPage (that you have redirected to).

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a new value to `window.location.href` creates a redirect for the browser. At this point, no further code is executed. If you would like to change the browser URL **without** redirection. Use the `pushState` function in the browser. [Here is an excellent example and explanation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_pushState()_method).